# Pytorch Multi-GPU Issue

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

I want to train my model with 2 GPU(id 5, 6), so I run my code with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=5,6 train.py`. However, when I printed torch.cuda.current_device I still got the id `0` rather than 5,6. But torch.cuda.device_count is `2`, which semms right. How can I use GPU5,6 correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely correct. PyTorch only sees two GPUs (therefore indexed 0 and 1) which are actually your GPU 5 and 6.

Check the actual usage with `nvidia-smi`. If it is still inconsistent, you might need to set an environment variable:

```
export CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID
```

(See [Inconsistency of IDs between 'nvidia-smi -L' and cuDeviceGetName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123252/inconsistency-of-ids-between-nvidia-smi-l-and-cudevicegetname))

Answer (score 0):

you can check the device name to verify whether that is the correct name of that GPU. However, I think when you set the Cuda_Visible outside, you have forced torch to look only at that 2 gpu. So torch will manually set index for  them as 0 and 1. Because of this, when you check the current_device, it will output 0

Comment: Can I set both of them to be the current device? That is because I want to use both of them.

Comment: yes, of course. You can use this example as source https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html.

Comment: because, multiple gpu only use for parallel processing. If you dont declare your model for  multiple gpu use, it will automatically set for a single GPU with index 0