# If I have multiple Nvidia GPUs in my system, how to check which GPU is currently used by CUDA compiler?

Tags: cuda

I have a windows system with 2 Nvidia GPUs. Can someone tell me which GPU is the CUDA compiler using? Is it possible to switch the GPUs or use both together for same process?

Comment: The compiler had absolutely nothing to do with what GPU your code will run on. You decide that, either in code or via runtime settings or a mixture of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0

Use 'cudaGetDeviceCount' to get the number of devices. If deviceCount is 2, then device index 0 and device index 1 refer to the two current devices.

And 'cudaGetDeviceProperties' can be used to get many properties of the device.

For example,

```
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, 1);
```

can be used to get many properties of device 1.

And the way to switch to different GPUs is easy. After initialization, use

```
'cudaSetDevice(0)'
```

and

```
'cudaSetDevice(1)'
```

to switch to different GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

The `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable will allow you to modify this enabling/ordering.

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1"` will enable both GPU devices to be available to your program.

Possible duplicate of [CUDA GPU selected by position, but how to set default to be something other than device 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628407/cuda-gpu-selected-by-position-but-how-to-set-default-to-be-something-other-than)